# Regex that catches wrong defined attributes?

Tags: regex, regex-negation

I'm trying to write a regex that catches wrong attributes defined.

In my case, plural="y" and plural="n" are the only two correct definitions, so I'd like to catch all other possibilities like:

```
plural="no"
plural="m"
plural="yn"
plural="mu"
plural="hahahhaaha"
```

etc.

Comment: Can you share your code/regex that you tried?

Comment: Also please indicate the language you are using, as each has slightly different variations. (And in this case, why not just compare against the literal Y or N instead of mucking about with regular expressions?)

Comment: I’m using Sublime search, trying to catch the problematic attributes in xml files quickly. - “Sublime Text uses the Perl Compatible Regular Expressions (PCRE) engine from the Boost library to power regular expressions in search panels.” Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex to select any string other than where `plural="y"` and `plural="n"`

```
\bplural="(?![yn]")[^"]+"
```

**Regex explanation:**

- `\b` - A word boundary to avoid matching plural partially in a larger string
- `plural="` - Matches this text literally
- `(?![yn]")` - This negative lookahead ensures it discards the match if the text followed is either `y"` or `n"`

  - `[^"]+"` - Matches one or more any character then finally matches a `"`

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ktYU4u/1/)**

On the other hand if you just want to match `plural="y"` and `plural="n"`, you can use this regex,

```
\bplural="[yn]"
```

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ktYU4u/2)**